# Folder name is "unknown" with Apache build application in Windows 10

Tags: java, ant, windows-10, build.xml

We used Apache Ant to build Windows application from Java binary. It generates Windows installer binary. After running that installation, it successfully deployed and every operation looks fine so far. However, the folder name of installation is "unknown", not "myApp", the name of our solution. I installed that installer in Windows 10. How can I fix the folder name as our solution's name?

Thnaks in advance,

Following is my build.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project 
    name="myApp-win32" 
    default="do-deploy" 
    basedir="." 
    xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">

    <property name="version" value="2.0.4" />
    <property name="java.myhome" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin" />

    <target name="init-fx-tasks">
        <path id="fxant">
            <filelist>
                <file name="${java.myhome}/../lib/ant-javafx.jar" />
                <file name="${java.myhome}../jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar" />
                <file name="${basedir}" />
            </filelist>
        </path>

        <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml" uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant" classpathref="fxant" />
    </target>

    <target name="do-deploy" depends="init-fx-tasks">
        <delete dir="deploy" />
        <delete dir="dist" />
        <mkdir dir="dist" />
        <mkdir dir="dist/libs" />
        <mkdir dir="deploy" />

        <copy todir="dist">
            <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/../bin" includes="*" excludes="*.jar" />
        </copy>

        <copy todir="dist/libs">
            <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/../bin" includes="*.jar" />
        </copy>

        <fx:resources id="appRes">
            <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/**"/>
            <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="myApp.jar"/>
        </fx:resources>

        <fx:jar destfile="dist/myApp.jar">
            <fx:application 
                id="myApp"
                name="myApp" 
                mainClass="com.xxxx.myApp.myApp" 
                version="${version}"
            />
            <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/../bin" includes="jspWin.*"/>
            <fx:resources refid="appRes" />
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="xxxx Ltd" />
                <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="myApp-win32" />
                <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${version}" />
                <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None" />
            </manifest>
        </fx:jar>

        <fx:deploy embedJNLP="false" 
                   extension="false" 
                   includeDT="false" 
                   offlineAllowed="true" 
                   outdir="${basedir}/deploy" 
                   nativeBundles="all" 
                   updatemode="background"
                   verbose="true"
                   >

            <fx:platform basedir="${java.myhome}/../"/>      
            <fx:resources>
                <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="**" excludes="*.log"/>
            </fx:resources>
            <fx:application 
                name="FastGPS"
                mainClass="com.myApp.myApp" 
                version="win32-${version}-installer"
                />
            <!--fx:info title="myApp">
                <fx:icon href="tr.ico" kind="shortcut"
                        width="32" height="32" depth="8"/> 
            </fx:info-->            
        </fx:deploy>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue with adding this syntax to build.xml

```
<fx:info title="myApp" vendor="myVendor"/>
```

It will generate the folder with the same name "myVendor" and copy your myApp to that folder